# Sort LastUpdateTime not working quickbooks API PHP

Tags: php, api, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am getting the below error when i tried to retrieve Objects with the Simple Query in Quickbooks.

Invalid Property Name in Sort Criteria: LastUpdatedTime
BAD_QUERY_REQUESTQUERY_INVALID_SORT_CRITERIA

I tried to sort using name and some other values, its working but for CreateTime and  LastUpdatedTime, its not working.

**Used the below function to get the Quickbooks Vendors**

QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Vendor

**Query used to retrieve in order:**

PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=50&Sort=LastUpdatedTime OldestToNewest

**Response:**

Invalid Property Name in Sort Criteria: LastUpdatedTime
BAD_QUERY_REQUESTQUERY_INVALID_SORT_CRITERIA

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Post your code. Also, post the output of print($Service->lastRequest()); so we can see what the request you're sending to Intuit looks like.

Comment: Added the code. Pls check it

Comment: Edit your original post and add the code to your original post. Otherwise your code looks like part of a *answer*, not part of the question.

Comment: What type of object are you querying for?

Comment: I want to get vendors from Quickbooks. I also want to retrieve it in order.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/0100_calling_data_services/0030_retrieving_objects

It appears as if you're trying to sort by a field that doesn't exist.

Are you sure you didn't mean:

```
LastUpdatedTime
```

Instead of:

```
LastUpdateTime
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry Its LastUpdatedTime. I misspelled it.

Answer (score 0):

My Code and Response

### Code:

```
        $ServiceName = "QuickBooks_IPP_Service_".$module;
            $Service = new $ServiceName();

        if ($creds['qb_flavor'] == QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::FLAVOR_ONLINE)
            {
            $qbmodule = "QB".$module;
            $updatedtime = getLastSyncDetails($qbmodule);
            $query = "";
            if(!empty($updatedtime) && trim($updatedtime) != '')    
            {
                $time = str_replace(" ", "T", $updatedtime);
                $time = $time."-07:00";
                $query = array('Sort' => 'LastUpdatedTime OldestToNewest'); 
            }
            }

        $list = array();
        $responseQuery = array();
            $responseQuery = $Service->findAll($Context, $realm, $query, $page, $limit);
```

### Response

Content-Type: application/xml

Invalid Property Name in Sort Criteria: LastUpdatedTime

BAD_QUERY_REQUEST

QUERY_INVALID_SORT_CRITERIA

Comment: can you check if the lastupdatedtime is not having any offset starting with '+'?